# stackoverflow badges critic awarded but not revoked

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely)

The [stackoverflow badge critic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/7/critic) is awarded as soon as you (accedintly) hit the downvote button. If you correct the downvote and correct it to upvote you keep the critic.

Comment: I suspect that this is by-design and a case really not worth fixing.

Comment: My critic badge on this meta was created by exactly this effect. But it's not really that big a deal -- it might mean I get the badge a bit early, but I would down-vote something for real sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

> The site admin has stated multiple
>   times that, by design, badges cannot
>   be lost or revoked, unless they were
>   obtained by cheating.
>
> However, if the criteria for a badge
>   no longer exist — e.g. the post it was
>   awarded for is deleted — the next
>   award of that badge is negated. When
>   badges are awarded, the system checks
>   to see how many you're supposed to
>   have, and only awards new badges when
>   the number of badges you're supposed
>   to have is greater than the number of
>   badges you have.
>
> As an example, suppose one of your
>   answers received 10 up-votes, which
>   caused you to earn the Nice Answer
>   badge. After you have the badge, that
>   same answer is down-voted to a score
>   under 10. The Nice Answer badge is not
>   revoked. However, the next time you
>   have an answer that gets 10 up-votes,
>   you will not earn an additional Nice
>   Answer badge, because the system sees
>   that you already have the number of
>   Nice Answer badges that you should
>   have.

Comment: This only works for "proper" badges and not tag badges though. If I have 100 votes in the `regex` tag and then get downvoted, I lose my bronze `regex` badge. Can't remember where I read this though, and apparently I can't find it again, so I might have read this in a dream...

Comment: I was proud of my [Great Answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer?userid=138231) badge here at Meta, but the original question was deleted by Jeff. I am now a bit ashamed of this badge since it suggests that I posted an utterly worthless answer.

Comment: @Chichiray: a parrot who can read and write English (albeit with a computer keyboard) has nothing to be ashamed of. Besides, ["Post is no longer available"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer?userid=138231) is good enough for me :)