# I don't think I deserve my badge

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Critic badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-awarded-prematurely)

I just accidentally clicked the down-vote arrow on an answer (my mouse was over it and my hand twitched). I realised my mistake and clicked it again to undo it.

I was surprised to receive a "Critics" badge for the down-vote.

Don't get me wrong - I fully intend to down-vote and earn my Critics badge fair and square but I would prefer not to win it by mistake.

P.S. *Do I get a badge for my first Meta question?* ;D

Comment: You do if it [gets some upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum)

Comment: Duplicate ... forgive me for wasting your time. Awesome site.

Answer (score 8):

This is more or less by design. Badges are usually not revoked if the action that caused them to be rewarded is undone somehow. For example, you keep any badges you earn from questions or answers that later got deleted. Only in extreme cases are badges revoked (manually).

Also, it's a bronze badge. Their purpose is for the most part to teach people how to use the site's basic functionality. You now know how to downvote, so I'd say it's well deserved.

Comment: I realise bronze badges are two-a-penny to you multi-K-pointers but ... I just don't deserve it. It would be so easy to detect an immediate undo and cancel the badge. It kind of reduces its worth. D'you see? I'm proud of my badges, meagre as they are at the moment (I'm working on that), and this just seems to devalue the others.

Comment: @Paul: If you feel that strongly about it, go to the [newest questions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), find a bad question and downvote it. We get a steady supply of them, so it shouldn't be too hard to find one that deserves it.

Comment: Will do - meanwhile I have registered my _slightly_ funny objections here [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-awarded-prematurely).