# Critic badge awarded in error - possibly bug

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, badges, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Critic badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-awarded-prematurely)

I do remember accidentally clicking a down-vote button, which I rectified at the same moment. But, I see `Critic` Badge being awarded to me on my Unix.SE profile.

Screenshot attached shows, I have given 0 down-votes and yet I have a critic badge

[image: Critic Badge in error]

This is possibly a bug I guess. Any way to rectify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's not a bug. The logs will show that you *did* cast a downvote. It will be something like this:

```
[01:23] downvote on post *x*
[01:23] undownvote on post *x*
```

So, in reality, you downvoted a post, and you deserve the badge. How soon after you cast the downvote you retracted the downvote doesn't matter.

Even so, it's just a simple bronze badge that is meant to teach you about downvoting. Does it really matter if you have it when you don't *really* feel you deserve it? I'm sure you'll cast a downvote at some point in the future.

Comment: Wow. You answer fast.

Comment: @juergend Just think, Tim Stone is faster than me.